# Assign multiple IP to Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking

I want to assign additional IP to my Ubuntu 14.02 server. My configuration is like:

```
auto eth0
auto eth0:0

iface eth0 inet static
    address xxx.xx.xx.xx
    netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    network xxx.xx.xx.x
    broadcast xxx.xx.xx.xxx
    gateway xxx.xx.xx.x

iface eth0:0 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

When I do, ifconfig. the eth0:0 is not visible in result.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108396/how-to-check-if-the-kernel-support-for-ip-alias

Comment: Also: http://inai.de/2008/02/19 and http://andys.org.uk/bits/2010/02/24/iproute2-life-after-ifconfig/

Answer (score 0):

That looks correHave you tried rebooting or running ifup eth0:0 to bring up the Interface ?

Also, setting a Gateway would seem to me to be suspicious -you only probably don't want to have 1 gateway in your config - if you are trying to multihome its a fair bit more complex then just adding 2 interfaces - you will need to use policy based (source) routing.